# Can't find config.rb in existing project that uses SASS

Tags: css, ruby, sass, compass

I want to use/compile SASS on an existing project (which has the SASS files ready, it's a template). But I can't find the config.rb so I don't know where to point the CMD(ruby) too. Can I create a new one or something?

Comment: Sass doesn't use config.rb

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450082/implement-compass-into-an-existing-sass-project

Comment: @cimmanon, I mean scss then

Comment: Again, Sass doesn't use config.rb.  The syntax you're using is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes it does? I can't use 'compass watch' without a config.rb in the root of my project.

Comment: Maybe you mean `config.RU`?

Comment: Compass and Sass are different programs.  You say that you need a config.rb for Sass, which is not true because Sass does not use a config.rb.  It is only *Compass* that needs a config.rb.

Comment: I think you know that I meant compass.

Comment: Why would I think that?  Users come here all the time asking for things that don't make sense because they don't understand what they're asking about at all.  This is not the first question I have come across where someone is running Sass and asking about config.rb, not realizing that they don't need a config.rb.

Comment: It's okay, you probably get a boner from correcting every little thing. Thanks for 0 help at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you are using Compass you can use `compass init`.

Which creates a `config.rb` file among other things.

```
directory sass/ 
directory stylesheets/ 
   create config.rb 
   create sass/screen.scss 
   create sass/print.scss 
   create sass/ie.scss 
    write stylesheets/ie.css
    write stylesheets/print.css
    write stylesheets/screen.css
```

There is a plethora of options available, see the [compass docs](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/)

And as @cimmanon and others have pointed out Sass and Compass are not the same thing. Compass is a SASS framework which provides some utilities (`compass watch`) on top of SASS. SASS is the cake, Compass is the frosting.

Comment: It's still not working, but I read it had something to do with Compass, someone from 31 august also had this problem.